# Rendering a JSON in Symfony [Problem with special characters]

Tags: php, html, json, symfony, encoding

I'm working on a project with symfony and I'm using the php function file_get_contents to return the content of this page https://db.satnogs.org/api/satellites/?format=json
which is basically a json format content.

the problem is when I render the content to the twig file the format changes like this

```
[{&quot;id&quot;:4105855,&quot;start&quot;:&quot;2021-05-14T10:45:53Z&quot;,&quot;end&quot;:&quot;2021-05-14T10:50:41Z&quot;,&quot;ground_station
...
```

I tried to clean the special characters by replacing " to " and I still got a problem because the backslash character also disappeared while rendering

for instance, this is the normal json format that I want to render

```
"client_metadata":"{\"radio\": {\"name\": \"gr-satnogs\",
...
```

here's the version that I have after rendering the json file

```
"client_metadata":"{"radio": {"name": "gr-satnogs",
```

I tried to put back the \ character but I didn't figure it out

**My question is** why does the render function in symfony alters the format of the file and do you know how to render the correct format in symfony (do I have to precise some encoding format in the parameter of the render function maybe) ?

I would be really grateful if you could help me! :)

Comment: Learn about [`autoscaping`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/twig.html#autoescape) and the [`raw`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/raw.html) filter.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, your json code is in a variable like `json`.

Usually, all output variables are escaped in twig. So, I think you've done something like this:

`{{ json }}`

If you're sure the data is save without being escaped, you can use the `raw` modifier:

`{{ json|raw }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by using the javascript `decodeURI()` function. In PHP, it is `urldecode()`.

```js
console.log(decodeURI(document.getElementById("mycode").innerHTML));
```

```html
<div id="mycode">[{&quot;id&quot;:4105855,&quot;start&quot;:&quot;2021-05-14T10:45:53Z&quot;,&quot;end&quot;:&quot;2021-05-14T10:50:41Z&quot;}]</div>
```